# Declaring a field tag in proto message

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I just dived in Go programming using protobuf and I'm at the point where I need to validate data in a struct. I found [govalidator](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator), which seems to do the perfect job for what I need. It does validate structs based on the field tags, something like

```
type Contact struct {
    firstName string `valid:"alpha,required"`
    lastName string `valid:"alpha,required"`
    email string `valid:"email,required"`
}

jdoe := &Contact{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "jdoe@mail.com"
}

ok, err = govalidator.ValidateStruct(jdoe)
```

And my protobuf definition would look like

```
message Contact {
    string firstName = 1;
    string lastName = 2;
    string email = 3;
}
```

Now my question would be, is there a way to define the field tags in the proto message. From what I've seen in the generated go code, the compiler adds tags to the fields anyway, but could I "sneak" the ones that I need too? Also, I would imagine that unmarshalling could be one possible solution, but it somehow seems inefficient to me to unmarshal just to copy the field values to an equivalent struct which would have the necessary field tags.

Comment: Not sure what `valid:"alpha,required"` does, but is it supposed to be a duplicate for `lastName` and `firstName`?

Comment: It is a quite common pattern to have different struct for message transporting (protobuf) and internal data processing. Sometimes you get away with using one (normally the messaging one), but as you see you run into troubles when you want different things from your internal struct. My advice: make a different one for internal purposes and copy.

Comment: @RickyA yes, it is supposed to be duplicate - these are the validation rules `govalidator` uses. And for the second part - that's exactly what I'm doing at the moment :-) Thanks

Comment: I do not know what you are building but if it is services related I can recommend using [gokit](https://github.com/go-kit/kit) in conjunction with grpc. It takes some time to wrap your head around, but in the end it is so much easier to maintain.

Comment: @RickyA Yes, service, using the micro framework indeed. I'll have a look at the gokit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same structure for the data encapsulation and the input coming from the client was just a pure coincidence. As it has been suggested not only in the comments, but also by co-workers more experienced (than me) with protobuf I've just mapped (1:1 in this particular case) the fields from the structure generated by proto to the data encapsulation structure I have defined.